# GruntJS. Building the project

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com) for building my project.

Here’s my 'build' task:

```
'clean:dist',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'autoprefixer',
'concat',
'ngmin',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'rev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin',
'html2js'
```

So I have all my JavaScript dependencies inside two files: `scripts.js` and `vendor.js`. These files are created by 'concat' task using 'usemin' blocks.

After building I have 404 error in the console: the script can't find some dependencies. But if I move them from `dev` folder and put the same path inside `dist` folder it works.

Also if I change dependencies after building project from `vendor.js` to list of JavaScript files (like in development version) it works again.

Has anybody faced such a problem? I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: When you say 'dependencies' do you mean all of your `<script>` tags are in the usemin blocks?  Or somethind else?

Comment: yes, I mean all <script> tags inside usemin blocks

Comment: Please post your usemin config from your `Gruntfile` and also the usemin blocks from your HTML.